# Programatic Screenshot of Container Hidden Behind an Image

Tags: ios, swift, uigraphicscontext

So I'm already using this code to screenshot a particular area (a table cell) that's visible on the screen:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(inputView.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
inputView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() as UIImage
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
let cellSnapshot : UIView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

However, now my goal is something more complicated:

1. First, programmatically screenshot entire screen
2. Present that to the user, essentially blinding them for a moment
3. Then I'll move some stuff around behind the image

**Tricky part...** While the image is still hiding the new setup, I want to screenshot/capture an image of that arrangement of views (includes every single view under the image).

**Why Do This?** The VC doesn't change but I'm going to slide in the 2nd image, giving the appearance that this new arrangement is a new screen.

Is this possible?

Comment: This seems possible, but much much more troublesome than just creating a new ViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the code to take a snapshot of any view! Just paste this function in and pass it the view you want to capture!

```
let pictureOfView = snapshotOfView(passAViewHere)

func snapshotOfView (inputView: UIView) -> UIView {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(inputView.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    inputView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() as UIImage
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    let cellSnapshot : UIView = UIImageView(image: image)
    cellSnapshot.layer.masksToBounds = false

    return cellSnapshot
}
```